Cómo resuelvo este problema al migrar un proyecto Django con PostgreSQL?
Tengo este problema cuando quiero hacer un python manage.py makemigrations en mi app. Estoy conectando a una base de datos PostgresSQL. Intente reinstalar el modulo de psycopg pero me sigue lanzando el mismo error.


Perdon si mi pregunta es muy tonta o no estoy formulando bien la pregunta, es la primera vez que uso stackoverflow

Pulsa en [edit] y pon tanto el código como los mensajes de error como texto, con formato. No todos pueden ver las imágenes.

si se necesita la libreria psycopg2 o psycopg2-binary pero talvez si la tienes instalada, talvez el error es el bug que tiene python en sus ultimas verciones con dicha libreria, vuelve a descargar python  pero verifica que cuando lo descargues sea una vercion segura, ahi mismo en las descargas aparece a un lado si es segura o aun tiene bugs, eso me resolvio el mismo problema que tienes tu, yo tengo el python 3.11.0

Solo tienes que instalar la librería psycopg2:
pip install psycopg2-binary

